# Display element for one person on hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering a list of students, some of which have failed their exams. For those who have failed their exams, I display a red square behind their avatars.

Whenever I hover over a student's avatar I want to display the subject that student has failed. My issue at the moment is that I display the `subjects` for all students, not only the one I've hovered over.

How can I display only the `mainSubject` for the student who's avatar I hovered on?

Here is a link to my code sandbox: [Example Link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/billowing-browser-9crlu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Code relevant to your problem needs to be contained directly inside your question, in text form and properly formatted - not just dumped onto an external platform. (You can provide such links for people to be able to more easy test your stuff, but the question needs to be self-contained.)

Answer (score 3):

I solved it like following.

- Get the id of the hovered student. Match this id from the list of students you render. if its match then show the subjects
- Also, I renamed the hook
- add key prop

you can check this too https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-bhaskara-mi83k

```
    const [hoveredStudentId, setHoveredStudentId] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      {students.map((student, i) => {
        return (
          <div className="student-card" key={i}>
            <p>
              {student.firstName} {student.lastName}
            </p>
            {student.passed === false ? (
              <>
                <img
                  id={student.id}
                  src={student.picture}
                  className="student-avatar fail"
                  onMouseEnter={e => {
                    setHoveredStudentId(e.currentTarget.id);
                  }}
                  onMouseLeave={e => {
                    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
                    setHoveredStudentId(0);
                  }}
                  alt="avatar"
                />
                {hoveredStudentId === student.id && (
                  <div className="subject-label">{student.mainSubject}</div>
                )}
              </>
            ) : (
              <img
                src={student.picture}
                className="student-avatar"
                alt="avatar"
              />
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Just a pointer, you should add an explanation as to what and why you have changed. Your code must work but what mistake OP made and how to rectify is what readers are looking for. Not just corrected code

Answer (score 1):

> Issue is that you have a list of students but only 1 flag to show/hide subjects.

**Solution: 1**

Maintain a list of flag/student. So you will have n flags for n students. Simple way for this is to have a state in a way:

```
IStudentDetails { ... }
IStudentStateMap {
  id: string; // uniquely identify a syudent
  isSubjectVisible: boolean;
}
```

And based on this flag `isSubjectVisible` toggle visibility.

[Updated code](https://codesandbox.io/embed/boring-sun-pv5pv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

---

**Solution 2:**

Instead of handling it using React, use CSS tricks. Note this is a patch and can be avoided.

#### Idea:

- Wrap Student in a container element and add a class `onHover` on elements on elements that needs to be shown on hover.
- Then use CSS to show/hide those elements.

```
.student-container .onHover {
  display:none;
}
.student-container:hover .onHover{
  display: block;
}
```

This way there wont be rerenders and no need for flags.

[Updated Code](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dry-moon-vhvf5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

---

However, solution 1 is better as you have more control and when you are using a UI library, its better to let it do all mutation and you should follow its ways.